# Como enviar múltiplas requisições para mesma URL (mesma API) em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, post, python-requests

Estou chamando uma API que cria tabela no Hive.
Estou desenvolvendo um script de teste automatizado para fazer 30 requisições e conseguir criar 30 tabelas no Hive. Para isso, coloquei uma lógica em que o nome_tabela a cada requisição fica nome_tabela_0, nome_tabela_1 e assim por diante (fiz com range).

Porém, quando executo a função, apenas a primeira tabela é inserida no Hive (nome_tabela_0) e retorna status_code 200. A requisição das demais retorna status_code 200 mas as tabelas não são criadas no Hive.

Alguém tem sugestões para conseguir de fato que as outras requisições sejam atendidas e as tabelas criadas?

```
def tests_requests_loops(table_sufix: str):

      nome_tabela = f"nome_tabela_{table_sufix}"

      body = {
        "name_table": nome_tabela,
        "schema_table": "{\"name\": \"Value\", \"type\": \"record\", \"namespace\": \"com.demo.producer.avro\", \"fields\": [{\"name\": \"id\", \"type\": \"int\"}, {\"name\": \"first_name\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"]}",
        "location":"hive-desenvolvimento"
      }
      print(body)

      url = "https://api-dev-cloud/development/ingestion-events/configuracoes"

      response = requests.request("POST", url, data=json.dumps(body), verify=False)
      print(response)

for i in range(30):
      tests_requests_loops(table_sufix=i)
```

**Obs:** tem os parâmetros de headers mas retirei pois não fazia muito diferença para a pergunta.

Comment: O código parece correto. A primeira requisição também retorna 200?

Comment: Isso, a primeira também retorna 200.

Comment: Deveria funcionar. Você pode criar uma API MOCK para interceptar as requisições e ver se está enviando tudo corretamente. Se sim, o problema não está no seu código.

Comment: Obrigada, Woss. Fiz alguns mocks, o código está correto. O Hive não estava aceitando o mesmo location para as mesmas requisições, então tive que colocar esse parâmetro no range também. Quem quiser fazer múltiplas requisições para uma mesma URL, essa é uma forma simples mas que resolve o problema.

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que seu problema não esteja na concepção de "enviar multiplas requisições". Mas já parou pra validar este seu dicionario python misturado com json em string.... No qual você ainda converte para json, ao enviar post? Se você tivesse criado um dicionário e depois convertido, teria visto o erro de sintax... Ou outra idéia seria utilizar o parametro [json](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) que já realiza está conversão.

```
def tests_requests_loops(table_sufix):

    body = {
            "name_table": f"nome_tabela_{table_sufix}",
            "schema_table": {
                    "name": "Value",
                    "type": "record",
                    "namespace": "com.demo.producer.avro",
                    "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "int"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "first_name",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                    ]
            }
    }

    url = "https://api-dev-cloud/development/ingestion-events/configuracoes"
    response = requests.request("POST", url, json=body, verify=False)
    return response
```